# Iterate through a String,Vector LinkedHashmap and print the full vector

Tags: java

I have LinkedHashMap defined as such.

```
LinkedHashMap<String,Vector<String>> hash = new LinkedHashMap<String,Vector<String>>();
```

I am trying to iterate through the hashmap and print the results for each key to a text file. Currently it is only returning the first value within each vector.

```
        for(Map.Entry<String,Vector<String>> entry : hash.entrySet()){
            printWriter.println(">NM_"+sID+"_"+entry.getKey());
            printWriter.println(entry.getValue());
        }
```

For example it is writing like this:

```
NM_152486.2_rheMac3
[MSKGILQVHPPICDCPGCRISSPV]
```

But really it should be writing something more like this:

```
NM_152486.2_rheMac3
MSKGILQVHPPICDCPGCRISSPVVA-RVGRLFYMTGFPLAFPPPSAALRPPERELSLPHRPTSTSSSSSPYSG--PTPGCSSPKRENG--TP-------------
```

Comment: `Vector` has been obsolete since 1998. How many years have you been programming in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for-each loop

```
    LinkedHashMap<String,Vector<String>> hash = new LinkedHashMap<String,Vector<String>>();

    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
    v.add ("a");
    v.add ("b");

    hash.put("key", v);

    for(Map.Entry<String,Vector<String>> entry : hash.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());

        for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

**edit**

Based upon your question I can not figure out where the `-` are coming from, but you can format as necessary

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me (i.e. prints all elements of the vector, separated by commas like this: [abc,def,ghijklmnop] )

I tried simulating your problem with this code:

```
        try {
        PrintWriter printwriter = new PrintWriter(new File("d:\\a.txt"));
        Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
        v.add("abc");
        v.add("def");
        v.add("ghijklmnop");
        Vector<String> v2 = new Vector<String>();
        v2.add("111");
        v2.add("222");
        v2.add("333");
        LinkedHashMap<String,Vector<String>> hash = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        hash.put("a1", v);
        hash.put("b2",v2);
        for(Map.Entry<String,Vector<String>> entry : hash.entrySet()){
            printwriter.println(">NM_"+entry.getKey());
            printwriter.println(entry.getValue());
        }
        printwriter.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

file contents are:

> NM_a1
>   [abc, def, ghijklmnop]
>
> NM_b2
>   [111, 222, 333]

Is it possible that the linkedhashmap values contain vectors that have only 1 element?

Can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: Sorry I should have included everything. Instead I just made a new question which is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106956/getting-weird-output-from-linkedhashmap

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you should take a look at is using a nested loop:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Vector<String>> entry : hash.entrySet()){
        printWriter.println(">NM_"+sID+"_"+entry.getKey());
        for (String nestedString : entry.getValue())
        {
            printWriter.print(nestedString);
            printWriter.print("-");
        }
        printWriter.println();
    }
```

However, I would expect the Vector toString() method, which is being called when you called

```
printWriter.println(entry.getValue());
```

to write a comma-separated list of its values. (see http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.util/Vector/Java_Vector_toString_.htm). Since it does not seem to be doing this, maybe somewhere in your code you only add one String to each Vector?
Try experimenting with this:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Vector<String>> entry : hash.entrySet()){
        printWriter.println(">NM_"+sID+"_"+entry.getKey());
        for (String nestedString : entry.getValue())
        {
            printWriter.print(nestedString);
            printWriter.print("-");
        }
        printWriter.println(" " + entry.getValue().size());
    }
```

to see if there is indeed only one string in each vector.